# merge images with text

Tags: php, image, merge, gd

Is there a way to put text on a png and then merge it wit a jpg / gif image?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a bit more? What do you mean with merge png with jpg/gif image?

Answer (score 3):

you can draw any text in or on image with gd using ttf or type1 fonts ( if its enabled in gd in php).

http://hr.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php

Answer (score 1):

Here's how i do it.

```
/* load the image */
$im = imagecreatefrompng("image.png");

/* black for the text */
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

/* put the text on the image */
imagettftext($im, 12, 0, 0, 0, $black, "arial.ttf", "Hello World");

/* load the jpg */
$jpeg = imagecreatefromjpeg("image.jpeg");

/* put the png onto the jpeg */
/* you can get the height and width with getimagesize() */
imagecopyresampled($jpeg,$im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $jpeg_width, $jpeg_height, $im_width, $im_height);

/* save the image */
imagejpeg($jpeg, "result.jpeg", 100);
```

This is a pretty simple example though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what language you're using, but [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) has APIs in a few different languages (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php).